# How to change UITableViewCell width in iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I have a view controller with a table view.  The UITableViewCell width is set to 320 in IB.  Now, I want to use the view controller in iPad by adding it to a superview.  The superview's width is bigger than 320.  The table view shows on the superview.  The problem is that it only occupy 320.  How can I change the cell width to occupy whole superview's width?  Thanks.

Comment: The autoresizing mask should suite your needs here.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you need to create a custom UITableViewCell. Than you can overwrite the function

```
- (void) layoutSubviews
{
    [dateLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(10.f, 16.f, 80.f, 12.f)];
    [textLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(106.f, 16.f, self.frame.size.width-105.f + 1.f, 12.f)];
}
```

In that function the `self.frame.size.width` is the actual one.

And it works with rotation of the device, too.